# AxisFault SAXParseException; Premature end of file

Tags: java, xml, web, axis, saxparser

I got the following Exception as a response from a webservice.

The file xml is well valid and well formed.

AxisFault  faultCode:
 {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException 
 faultSubcode:   faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature
 end of file.  faultActor:   faultNode:   faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
 Premature end of file.

the SAXParseException lineNumber = -1 and ColumnNumber = -1

I searched a lot about this error but there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Verify request and response xml by posting thru SOAPUI manually. Probably you are not getting xml response from webservice call. Sometimes simple text and html responses cause problem.